# Responsive GUI when using Bluetooth LE

Tags: delphi, bluetooth-lowenergy, firemonkey, android-bluetooth

Delphi 10.3 Rio, Android 8

When I am using BLE in the code (subscribing, readind, writing...), my GUI is frozen for several seconds. I'd like to give immediate feedback to the user that an action is currently processed.

How can I make sure that the few lines of code (i.e. displaying a progress wheel) will be displayed right after the click event and before any BLE transaction?

Comment: Perform the bluetooth code in a thread...

Comment: When the GUI is frozen, it indicates that you need to put that work into a thread. Then you can either give progress feedback from the thread via synchronize calls or use a timer.